# undefined variable login message

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I have this registration page, and I call the method `reg_check()` on $user. I get errors messages, and they are displayed if some inputs haven't been filled. But when I fill all of it I get an error message "undefined variable".

I tried to put $message=" "  in different places in method and regPage but still getting error: undefined variable login message

This is on registration page:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
//$message = "";
$user->reg_check();
}else
{ 
  $message = "";
}
?>
```

Problem on this line:
NOTICE: UNDEFINED VARIABLE: MESSAGE IN...

```
<h4 class="bg-danger"><?php echo $message; ?></h4>
```

reg_check method

```
   public function reg_check()
{


    global $baza;
    switch(isset($_POST)){   

        case empty($_POST['pass']):
            //                header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 
            $message = "Upišite šifru u odgovorajuće polje";
            break;
        case ($_POST['pass']<5):
            //                header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 
            $message = "Vaša šifra mora biti duža od 5 karaktera";
            break;
        case empty($_POST['email']):
            //                header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 

            $message = "Upišite mail u odgovarajuće polje";
            break;  

             case isset($_POST['email']):


            $email = $baza->sanitize($_POST['email']); 
            $cmail=['mail'=>$email];    
            $postoji = $baza->prep_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :mail limit 1",$cmail);
            $count= count($postoji->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

            if($postoji->rowCount() > 0){
                //                    header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 
                $message = "Korisnik sa email: " . $email . " već postoji!";

            }
            else
            {  $message = "";
             $this->registration($_POST);

            }
            break;
    }

}
```

Comment: That's probably a [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) problem. You are setting the value of `$message` in the function, but try to access it outside. Try using `global` just like you did with `$baza`

Comment: I can see you don't return $message and don't get in $user->reg_check(); CHANGE to ==> echo $user->reg_check();

Comment: global $message in method solved the problem

Comment: @Xigo you should **not** use a global for this kind of variable, look at my answer for the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access a variable defined and set inside you class. You need to get it out of the box with a method. You have one already $message. The only thing you need to do is return it. So that when you call the mehtod `reg_check()`, you get  a value (the message). That way you can retrieve variables from inside your class.

```
<?php

public function reg_check()
{
  global $baza;

  switch(isset($_POST)){   

    case(empty($_POST['pass'])):
      // header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 
      $message = "Upišite šifru u odgovorajuće polje";
      break;

    case($_POST['pass'] < 5):
      // header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 
      $message = "Vaša šifra mora biti duža od 5 karaktera";
      break;

    case(empty($_POST['email'])):
      // header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 
      $message = "Upišite mail u odgovarajuće polje";
      break;  

    case(isset($_POST['email'])):
      $email = $baza->sanitize($_POST['email']); 
      $cmail=['mail'=>$email];    
      $postoji = $baza->prep_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :mail limit 1",$cmail);
      $count= count($postoji->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

      if($postoji->rowCount() > 0) {
        // header( "refresh:4;url=reglog.php" ); 
        $message = "Korisnik sa email: " . $email . " već postoji!";
      } else {
        $message = "";
        $this->registration($_POST);
      }
      break;
  }

  // when all of the switch() case: as been done return the message
  return $message;

}
```

Then on any file where you have defined $user as a new instance of you class. You can call in the method and get in return a value.

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  // echo the value returned by the method `reg_check()`
  $message = $user->reg_check();
} else {
  $message = '';
}

echo $message;
```

**Or in one line**

```
echo isset($_POST['submit']) ? $user->reg_check() : '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your defining a new $message ina function you should return the result back again. Like this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
     $message = $user->reg_check();
}

public function reg_check()
{
 .....
 return $message;
}
```

Or just do echo $user->reg_check();

Answer (score 0):

Initializing `$message` to an Empty string in your method should be enough. And you should not forget to return your `$message` at the end of your method...

```
<?php

    public function reg_check(){
        global $baza;
        $message = "";

        switch(isset($_POST)){
            case empty($_POST['pass']):
                $message = "Upišite šifru u odgovorajuće polje";
                break;
            case ($_POST['pass']<5):
                $message = "Vaša šifra mora biti duža od 5 karaktera";
                break;
            case empty($_POST['email']):
                $message = "Upišite mail u odgovarajuće polje";
                break;

            case isset($_POST['email']):
                $email      = $baza->sanitize($_POST['email']);
                $cmail      =['mail'=>$email];
                $postoji    = $baza->prep_query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = :mail limit 1",$cmail);
                $count      = count($postoji->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ));

                if($postoji->rowCount() > 0){
                    $message = "Korisnik sa email: " . $email . " već postoji!";
                }else {  
                    $this->registration($_POST);
                }
                break;
        }
        // YOU MUST RETURN $message AS IT IS NECESSARY IN YOUR CASE....
        return $message;
    }
?>


<?php
    $message = "";

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $user->reg_check();
    }
?>


    <h4 class="bg-danger"><?php echo $message; ?></h4>
```